# IntelliJ - How to re-enable the "Update Project" popup

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

In IntelliJ, when updating a project, the following popup appears:

[image]

If, as in the picture, we choose to not show this dialog in the future, how can we be asked again if we want to change something in our update strategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that if you click on the VCS update button [image] while holding the Shift key, the popup reappears.

I hope this helps.